# escape sed in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I wish to put some numbers in my result txt files using shell script and sed, like:

```
for i in 0.88 0.90 0.92 0.94 0.96 0.98 1.00 1.02 1.04 1.06 1.08 1.10 1.12; do
    a_original_A=5
    amod=`bc <<< "$i*$a_original_A"`
    sed -s -i '1i|/\"list_number_$i  $amod  $amod  $amod  90  90  90" ' list_${i}.txt
    sed -s -i '1i\12' list_${i}.txt
done
```

But it didn't work. I tried to use sed with escaping, but failed; I tried

```
sed -s -i '1i|/\"list_number_$i  ${amod}  ${amod}  ${amod}  90  90  90" ' list_${i}.txt
```

But this doesn't help as well.

Here, I wish to make 13 number of txt files, and wish to put changing numbers at the second line of 13 txt files. For example, list_0.88.txt contains

```
12
list_number_0.88    4.4   4.4   4.4   90   90   90
```

Those two lines at the beginning of the file. 4.4 is coming from 5*0.88. Likewise, I wish to make 13 files, to have different numbers in 2nd line. How can I use numbers in sed command?

NB: There are already 13 non-empty text files; I wish to add these new lines as the first two lines in each of the existing files.

Comment: Do the files list_0.88, list_0.90, ... exist? Are they empty? To use `sed '1i ...'` command to insert a line, the file must not be empty.

Comment: @zhliu03 Yes there are already 13 txt files, I wish to put first two lines to the files....

Comment: have you tried `sed -s -i "1i list_number_$i  $amod  $amod  $amod  90  90  90" list_${i}.txt` ?  and `sed -s -i "1i 12" list_${i}.txt` This works for me.

Comment: @zhliu03 Wow that is very simple. It seems like I need to use ", not '.... Thank you

Comment: You should only need one `sed` command per file, either by including both `1i` commands after their own `-e` option (`sed -i -e "1i …" -e "1i …"`) which works with GNU `sed` (but not classic variants of `sed`), or by doing things with the classic notation, with a backslash-newline after `1i` and then `12\` on the next line, and then the `list_number_$i` bit on the third line.  You need to worry about single vs double backslashes because you'll be using double quotes to allow variables to be expanded.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the lessons regarding the usage of sed, and yes, double quoates were the key here. I really appreciate your reply for me. I really need to learn a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What on earth are you doing trying to use shell plus sed plus bc for this??? The general purpose UNIX text manipulation tool is awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    a_original_A = 5
    split("0.88 0.90 0.92 0.94 0.96 0.98 1.00 1.02 1.04 1.06 1.08 1.10 1.12",nums)
    for (i in nums) {
        num = nums[i]
        out = "list_" num ".txt"
        amod = num * a_original_A
        print "12" > out
        print "list_number_" num, amod, amod, amod, 90, 90, 90" > out
        close(out)
    }
}'
```

wrt your comment below, if you already have files in your directory then with GNU awk (which I assume you have since you're using GNU sed in your example) it'd be:

```
awk -i inplace '
BEGIN { a_original_A = 5 }
FNR==1 {
    num = gensub(/.*_/,"",1,FILENAME)
    amod = num * a_original_A
    print "12"
    print "list_number_" num, amod, amod, amod, 90, 90, 90"
}
{ print }
' list_*.txt
```

Comment: Actually, the reason why I choose sed is because I wish to insert first two lines to 13 files. There are already 13 files in the folder, and I tried to put first two lines to all files. I'm sure that awk can do the same work, but I couldn't find how. But I really wish that I could be the awk pro like you :P

Comment: It becomes simpler if the files already exist, I just added that solution to my answer. Just read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. Awk is orders of magnitude simpler to use than shell+sed+etc. and the solutions you end up with will be far more robust, portable, efficient, concise, etc. You just have a couple of concepts to understand (implicit read loop and condition { action } syntax) and the rest is basically a much stripped-down C with associative arrays.

Answer (score 1):

First , you have "list_0.88.txt , list_0.90.txt ... " , and so on , right ?
As your wish , I think we can modify the shell like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "0.88 0.90 0.92 0.94 0.96 0.98 1.00 1.02 1.04 1.06 1.08 1.10 1.12"
do
        a_original_A=5
        amod=`bc <<< "$i*$a_original_A"`
        echo "---->$amod"
        echo "12" > /tmp/tmpfile
        echo "list_number_$i  $amod  $amod  $amod  90  90  90" >> /tmp/tmpfile
        cat list_${i} >> /tmp/tmpfile
        cp -rf list_${i}.txt list_${i}.txt.bak
        cp -rf /tmp/tmpfile list_${i}.txt
done
```

Comment: Using a single string for the list of factors like that is not going to work with `bc`, for starters.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible ways to do this.  This code uses the `seq` command to generate the range of numbers.  It comes in 3 parts.  The first part creates the 'pre-existing' files.

The second part shows two ways of editing the files.  The version with the line (tag) `12A` doesn't require support for `-i` from `sed` (it isn't standard, and the behaviour of GNU `sed` is different from the behaviour of BSD (Mac OS X) `sed`).  The version with the line (tag) `12B` uses classical `sed` notation (which works with both GNU `sed` and other variants) to insert two lines of information before line 1 of the original text in the file.

```
# Generate 'pre-existing' files
for number in $(seq -f '%4.2f' 0.88 0.02 1.12)
do echo "Pre-existing data in file $number" > list_$number.txt
done

tmp=$(mktemp ./tmp.XXXXXX)
trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

for number in $(seq -f '%4.2f' 0.88 0.02 1.12)
do
    list="list_$number.txt"

    # Works without using sed
    {
    echo "12A"
    echo "$number" | awk '{ x=5*$1; printf("list_number_%4.2f %4.1f %4.1f %4.1f 90 90 90\n", $1, x, x, x) }'
    cat "$list"
    } > "$tmp"
    cp "$tmp" "$list"
    rm -f "$tmp"

    # Option 2 (as written, works with GNU sed and BSD sed)
    amod=$(echo "$number" | awk '{printf "%4.1f\n", 5*$1}')
    sed -i.bak -e "1i\\
    12B\\
    list_number_$number $amod $amod $amod 90 90 90" "$list"

done

trap 0 1 2 3 13 15
```

Sample output (`cat list_1.1?.txt`):

```
12B
list_number_1.10  5.5  5.5  5.5 90 90 90
12A
list_number_1.10  5.5  5.5  5.5 90 90 90
Pre-existing data in file 1.10
12B
list_number_1.12  5.6  5.6  5.6 90 90 90
12A
list_number_1.12  5.6  5.6  5.6 90 90 90
Pre-existing data in file 1.12
```

Obviously, the code assumes you have `seq`, but it is available as part of GNU CoreUtils and on Mac OS X.

Another technique altogether:

```
# Generate pre-existing files as before
for number in $(seq -f '%4.2f' 0.88 0.02 1.12)
do echo "Pre-existing data in file $number" > list_$number.txt
done

# Generate the two parameters from awk; use sed to edit each file in turn.
awk 'BEGIN { for (i = 0.88; i <= 1.12; i += 0.02) printf "%4.2f %4.1f\n", i, 5*i }' |
while read number amod
do
    list="list_$number.txt"
    sed -i.bak -e "1i\\
    12\\
    list_number_$number $amod $amod $amod 90 90 90" "$list"
done
```

Sample output (`cat list_1.1?.txt`):

```
12
list_number_1.10 5.5 5.5 5.5 90 90 90
Pre-existing data in file 1.10
12
list_number_1.12 5.6 5.6 5.6 90 90 90
Pre-existing data in file 1.12
```